# Structured Streaming Query Fails with "A file referenced in the transaction log cannot be found."

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am streaming from a delta table source and my queries keep failing with `A file referenced in the transaction log cannot be found`. The weird part is that when I run `fsck repair table table_name dry run` to see which files are missing it returns no results. Why would the streaming query think that there is a file missing from the transaction log while the fsck repair says there are none?

I have also tried running: `spark._jvm.com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaLog.clearCache()`

Comment: you don't have some retention policy on a storage account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that tables were being optimized and then vacuumed and then the streaming job was trying to read the transaction log but the files had been vacuumed. The fix was to increase the vacuum retention to be greater than what the latest reads from the streaming. The reason fsck did not work is because the files were not actually missing from the perspective of the latest state of the table.